# paypal is not working under firewall

Tags: php, paypal, firewall

I have a php application ,  and I'm trying to integrate with paypal payment gateway , my pc is under a fortinet firewall , now i'm struggling with a problem, when i'm trying to make payment with paypal it always retun an error

[L_ERRORCODE0] => 81002
 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Unspecified Method 
 [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Method Specified is not

but same application and database is copied to another pc which is not under the firewall works fine.

I thinking it's problem with my firewall.
I had opened 443 port on my firewall , is there anything do more on firewall ?
please anyone can give some adivce?

Comment: What method/action are you trying to do when you get that error message? Are you using express checkout?

Comment: yes, i got above error code when i use the express checkout method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opening 443 should be enough as https uses port 443. I don't know in details how paypal api works. is it possible that other ports are involved during the exchange your application - paypal api? try a tcpdump or watch the firewall log in order to see if there are packet exchanges on other ports and so are blocked by the firewall.

Comment: i just upgraded my xampp 1.7.3 to xampp 1.7.7 then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

My application is in .NET and has paypal integration. When i run the "live" code using my Visual Studio, it can easily connect with the Paypal site. But when publish the same package on the server it is unable to connect.

I have whitelisted all the IP of paypal but still facing this proble.